# Проблема при настройке nuxt.js с vuetify.js

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vuetify

Пробую установить nuxt в связке с vuetify (npx create-nuxt-app project-name) и выходит ошибка:
[image: вывод с терминала]

node.js: v14.15.3, windows 10
Подскажите, может кто сталкивался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу вариант который мне помог:

1. Установить Python версии 2.7(не выше). Я устанавливал вручную с сайта https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Указать в переменных окружения для параметра Path путь до Python, также с помощью команды можно указать:
   npm config set python [путь до python]
3. Произвести установку зависимостей в PowerShell под админом с помощью команды:
   npm install --global windows-build-tools
4. Установить node-gyp: npm install -g node-gyp

Comment: помогло  спасибо